# What is the best garden chess set?

Tags: chess-variants

We plan to buy a garden chess set for outside at our work facility. It should be mobile which means we don’t plan to build a chess board with stones on the ground.

What is a good garden chess set (and board)

- which is durable and robust, and
- which is not too lightweight (when there is some wind)?

Comment: Not an answer, but try googling "giant chess". You needn't lug 64 paving-slabs each time you want to move the board -- you can buy giant plastic boards that roll up. With the really giant sets, each piece has a hollow base and a top you can take off so that you can pour in sand or water to weight the thing down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This could be an option, the board itself is foldable, but its larger than your standard chess board

[Link](https://www.google.com/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwjSw-qu4933AhVSMSsKHUCdAvUYABADGgJzZg&ae=2&sig=AOD64_2ob7RnHRRF6a0aAwZ2NGWCQz9A-Q&adurl&ctype=5&ved=2ahUKEwjQkd6u4933AhXYyaACHWJ8AWQQwg96BAgBEEA&dct=1)

[image]

This is also fine, although it is **massive** and extremely expensive

[Link](https://www.google.com/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwjSw-qu4933AhVSMSsKHUCdAvUYABABGgJzZg&ae=2&sig=AOD64_2wznNcNLfww0t9IvH-hCYWtETMuw&adurl&ctype=5&ved=2ahUKEwjQkd6u4933AhXYyaACHWJ8AWQQwg96BAgBED0)

You can look for more boards online by searching "giant chess" or "garden chess set"

Comment: Looking at the first one, I just wonder if a board made up by 64 square which you attach together are not better. Since the surface might be more even